# Set properties including PDF file in Word via Visual Basic

Tags: vba, pdf, ms-word

I have edited an existing Visual Basic macro in Word so i can insert an PDF document as an OLEObject in Word. The problem now is, the PDF file isn't inserted with its original format, so i would like to resize/keep its original format.

The current code i use is:

```
Public Sub VervangTekstDoorLogo()
'
' VervangTekstDoorLogo Macro
'
'


   If ActiveWindow.View.SplitSpecial <> wdPaneNone Then
        ActiveWindow.Panes(2).Close
    End If
    If ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdNormalView Or ActiveWindow. _
        ActivePane.View.Type = wdOutlineView Then
        ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdPrintView
    End If
    ActiveDocument.PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = True
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageHeader
    Selection.TypeText Text:="<briefpapier>"
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "<briefpapier>"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False

    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute


    Dim LogoBestandKop As String
    Dim LogoBestandVoet As String

    LogoBestandKop = "c:\Document.PDF"


    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "<briefpapier>"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue


    End With


    Do While Selection.Find.Execute
      With Selection.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject(FileName:=LogoBestandKop, LinkToFile:=False)

          End With


            ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekMainDocument
            Selection.EscapeKey


 Loop

   'Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
   'Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
   'ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject LogoBestandKop

End Sub
```

Could anyone give me a heads up how to force the macro to keep it's original PDF size? I am aware hot to set attributes for picture objects, just not for OLEObjects.

Answer (score 0):

Any object you insert into Word will automatically be re-sized to fit into the available "text frame" - within a table cell, within a text box, within the margins of a page. You can try setting the margins to 0, assuming that the size of the original PDF matches the page size of the document you're trying to insert it into.

But please note that, if the PDF document comprises more than a single page you CANNOT force the OLE object to display all the pages. OLE containers don't work that way - they can show only the one page until the object has been opened by the associated OLE Server.